# Unable to read characters like ZÖE,DÉCOR CIARÁN etc from my XML?

Tags: java, xml, marklogic

I have a large XML. It has some characters like ZÖE,DÉCOR CIARÁN in my XML. I am using **Java** and **MarkLogic** as my DB. I am unable to read my **XML** with these words and when I remove these words and check it's working perfectly.

My Java Code:

```
    DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(IP, PORT,
        DATABASE_NAME, USERNAME, PWD, Authentication.DIGEST);

    XMLDocumentManager docMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
    DOMHandle xmlhandle = new DOMHandle();
    docMgr.read("/" + filename, xmlhandle);
```

Changed Question:
As i said i was unable to read special chars, now how can i insert the special characters so that while i am reading i get the same format.

Example:
When i insert characters like **CIARÁN AURÉLIE BARGÈME** it is saving but when i read,  the data is like this **CIARAN AURELIE BARGEME** but not as inserted.

```
 DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(IP, PORT,
        DATABASE_NAME, USERNAME, PWD, Authentication.DIGEST);

    XMLDocumentManager docMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
    DOMHandle xmlhandle = new DOMHandle();
    docMgr.read("/" + filename, xmlhandle);
    String doc = xmlhandle.ToString();
    String data = Normalizer.normalize(doc, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                    .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

Am using Normalizer to read special characters, else normal xmlhandle is fine.

Comment: You may have to set the encoding while loading the document, <encoding>utf-8</encoding> or auto

Comment: As I am using XMLStreamReaderHandle to write XML into markLogic,so it automatically converts i guess.Am i right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their official documentation:

If you specify the encoding and it turns out to be the wrong encoding, then the conversion will likely not turn out as you expect.

MarkLogic Server stores text, XML, and JSON as UTF-8. In Java, characters in memory and reading streams are UTF-16. The Java API converts characters to and from UTF-8 automatically.

When writing documents to the server, you need to know if they are already UTF-8 encoded. If a document is not UTF-8, you must specify its encoding or you are likely to end up with data that has incorrect characters due to the incorrect encoding. If you specify a non-UTF-8 encoding, the Java API will automatically convert the encoding to UTF-8 when writing to MarkLogic.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_11208

Comment: yes, as u said javaAPI will convert to UTF-8.Here Its working fine when i write characters like ®,€ these.It is converting to some and on reading its working fine.But the characters like i mentioned  ZÖE,DÉCOR CIARÁN are not converting to anyform.So what is causing the problem here. The XML file am using is encoded with ISO-8859-1.

Comment: You need to use > http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html

Comment: If `®` and `€` work then it is certainly not ISO-8859-1 since that doesn't contain those characters. It could be CP-1252 or ISO-8859-15 as those are both sometimes mislabelled as ISO-8859-1 or else used when ISO-8859-1 is called for (as they are both a perfect superset of it) and do contain those characters. All three encodings mentioned here contain `Á`, `É` and `Ö` too, though.

Comment: @SunilKumar , As u said now am able to read the characters, but those characters are like  ZOE,DECOR CIARAN but like  ZÖE,DÉCOR CIARÁN etc from my XML. Can you tell how how to read the characters same as in XML.

Comment: Can you try implementing InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")

Comment: @SunilKumar, Do i need to use while reading or writing.Can you plz tell me in detail.

Comment: Please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html